# Upsampling xarray DataArray similar to np.repeat()?

Tags: python-3.x, python-xarray

I'm hoping to upsample values in a large 2-dimensional DataArray (below). Is there an xarray tool similar to np.repeat() which can be applied in each dimension (x and y)? In the example below, I would like to duplicate each array entry in both x and y.

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(3)
y = np.arange(3)
x_mesh,y_mesh = np.meshgrid(x, y)
arr = x_mesh*y_mesh
df = xr.DataArray(arr, coords={'x':x, 'y':y}, dims=['x','y'])
```

Desired input:

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 2, 4]])
```

Desired output:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 4],
       [0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 4]])
```

I am aware of the `xesmf` regridding tools, but they seem more complicated than necessary for the application I have in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple solution for this with `np.kron`.

```
>>> arr
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 2, 4]])
```

```
>>> np.int_(np.kron(arr, np.ones((2,2))))
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 4],
       [0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 4]])
```

Comment: This is not using xarray.